# Passing a XML in Execute Immediate

Tags: oracle11g

```
      varSQL: = 'DECLARE


      varOptionId NUMBER;
      varXML XMLTYPE;
      varHsCode VARCHAR2(200);
      varHsCodeCount NUMBER;
      varId NUMBER;
      RVAL  OBJ_RETURN:=OBJ_RETURN(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

      BEGIN

      varXML:=:refXML;


      varHsCode:= varXML.EXTRACT('/OBJECT/HsCodes/HsCode/text()').GETSTRINGVAL();


      :out:=varHsCode;

       END';

       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE varSQL USING PXML,OUT varOut;
```

This gives the following error:

ORA-06550: line 9, column 15:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 9, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06512: at "BIZZXE_V2_SCH.SYSTEM_UTILITY", line 225
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Is it possible to pass a XML?

Comment: why don't you execute it directly?

Comment: No idea why you'd want to use dynamic SQL for that, but you have unescape single quotes in the varSQL string value so I'm surprised that compiles at all. We have no context, so can you confirm that the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is line 225 of your package body, and this is a run-time error not something you see when you compile the package?

Comment: And yes, you can pass an XMLType, just tried with a version of your code with some errors fixed - missing semicolon, incorrect assignment on the first line, escaped quotes. It would be helpful if you showed what you're actually running, as a complete block of code we can run to recreate the error you're seeing. Is PXML actually XMLType, or varchar2/CLOB? You'll get that error if it's a string, so pretty sure that's the issue.

Comment: I have only put a sample code. Thanks for your reply

Comment: PXML is of XMLTYPE

Comment: It works if it's XMLType. Again, show a complete self-contained block of code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can pass an XMLType variable as a bind parameter:

```
declare
    varsql varchar2(1024);
    varout varchar2(4);
    pxml xmltype := xmltype('<OBJECT><HsCodes><HsCode>Test</HsCode></HsCodes></OBJECT>');
begin
    varSQL := 'DECLARE
 varOptionId NUMBER;
 varXML XMLTYPE;
 varHsCode VARCHAR2(200);
 varHsCodeCount NUMBER;
 varId NUMBER;
 --RVAL  OBJ_RETURN:=OBJ_RETURN(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
 BEGIN
 varXML:=:refXML;

 varHsCode:= varXML.EXTRACT(''/OBJECT/HsCodes/HsCode/text()'').GETSTRINGVAL();

 :out:=varHsCode;
END;';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE varSQL USING PXML,OUT varOut;
    dbms_output.put_line(varOut);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Test
```

The error you are getting is because you have declared `PXML` as a string; either a `varchar2` or `CLOB` variable:

```
declare
    varsql varchar2(1024);
    varout varchar2(4);
</HsCodes></OBJECT>');
    pxml varchar2(64) := '<OBJECT><HsCodes><HsCode>Test</HsCode></HsCodes></OBJECT>';
begin
    varSQL := 'DECLARE
 varOptionId NUMBER;
 varXML XMLTYPE;
 varHsCode VARCHAR2(200);
 varHsCodeCount NUMBER;
 varId NUMBER;
 --RVAL  OBJ_RETURN:=OBJ_RETURN(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
 BEGIN
 varXML:=:refXML;

 varHsCode:= varXML.EXTRACT(''/OBJECT/HsCodes/HsCode/text()'').GETSTRINGVAL();

 :out:=varHsCode;
END;';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE varSQL USING PXML,OUT varOut;
    dbms_output.put_line(varOut);
end;
/

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 9, column 10:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 9, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06512: at line 21
```

In your example there's no reason to use dynamic SQL anyway, but maybe your real-world example is more complicated.